# In SQLAlchemy, Which is better to fetch the data in descending order or reverse() list the fetched data?

Tags: python, list, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have to fetch data in descending order. So what would be faster? fetch the data in descending order or reverse() the list of fetched data.

`Note:` I have been using SQLAlchemy in Flask framework. My application has to fetch hundreds of data from MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on if that sql table is indexed on the column that you are sorting.

If it is, let the query do the sorting. If it is not, it depends more on the parallelization of the sorting algo that you are running between the sql engine or your python code. If it is just hundreds of rows, it really wouldn't be significant performance difference between the two approaches if the table is not indexed on that column.